# Error when calculating for bivariate linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am a beginner at R and am trying to do a bivariate /multivariate regression analysis with an excel file. Despite having use this code before, I keep getting this recurring error.

I tried using = `bivariatemodel <- lm(y ~ x, data = dataset)` but I get the error

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

keeps popping up. Any suggestions on why this is happening in simple terms? Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of reasons this can happen. Please copy and paste the output of `dput(dataset)` so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that you are trying to invoke `lm` on `character` column. For linear regression the dependent variable `y` should be always a number. Using `character` as a dependent variable throws the error and warning you mentioned. So check, what is in `y` variable there should be numbers, not words/letters.

What is happenning here behind the scenes, `lm` is trying to convert your data from `character` into `double` type and  if they are alphabetic symbols returns `NA` for `y` column, but having all `NA` in dependent variable throws the error: no response for any predictor - `lm` cannot return any result.

Additionally it may happen that the decimal number representation in `Excel` is using coma `,` instead of `.` because of different locale setting. So check it as well as Excel columns can be treated as character vectors.

See the example below:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- letters[1:4]
lm(y ~ x)
```

Output:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
> :    NA/NaN/Inf in 'y' In addition: Warning message: In storage.mode(v)
> <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion